# How to access div class under ul and li

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to access div class under ul li to assign css style. Here I want to change dropdown element style under media query, how to access dropdown element.

Below is my code.

```
<ul class="nav" id="topnav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" >item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Services
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">sub item1</a>
                <a href="#">sub item2</a>
                <a href="#">sub item3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul li .dropdown`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector:

```
ul > li .dropdown{
    /*Style*/
}
```

It selects the `<li>`s that are descendants of ul and then the `.dropdown`.

Snippet:

```css
ul > li .dropdown{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav" id="topnav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" >item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Services
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">sub item1</a>
                <a href="#">sub item2</a>
                <a href="#">sub item3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to directly manipulate with the class like.

```
.dropdown{
  color: red;
}
```

The second option is to use descendants selector of css like.

```
ul > li .dropdown{
  color: red;
}
```

Here a very good article about tons of css selectors [css-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, a 100% reliable way ist to use `ul#topnav > li > .dropdown` as selector - this also uses the ID of the top level `ul` and only affects direct children of its first-level list items which have the `.dropdown` class.